# More formatting option for comment

Tags: discussion, comments, code-formatting

I've seen that there are a few formatting option for comment. In some comment I tried to write a few words in a new line but that I could not add new line in comment. I can understand that comment tools may not be as rich as reply tools but I think sometimes it is necessary to add these options in comment. Where can I get the formatting option for comment? And is there any new line option for comment?

Comment: It should not be necessary at all.

Answer (score 2):

> And is there any new line option for comment?

No, and I don't think there should be.

Comments are made to be short, asking for clarification or link to another page. You can make your comment "rich" by surrounding variables and methods with "`", exactly as you do in answers.

If you feel the need to have a new line, you might want to consider answering the question<sup>1</sup> instead of commenting on it.

<sup>1</sup> Really consider it :)

Comment: Careful how you state 'consider answering the question instead of commenting on it." If construed incorrectly, I can easily forsee a future "why was my answer flagged as not an answer" post on MSO. ;)

Comment: @SlyRaskal Edited :D

Comment: Best edit, EVAR!